# Adding a separator after each article in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to use an image to separate my articles (posts). I found this function below

```
function funny_cat_filter( $content ) {
$content .= '<img src="(image url)"/>';
 return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'funny_cat_filter' );
```

Don't mind the function name. This works just fine but with one little pesky detail. It adds image on pages also and I don't want that. I want this only to be added after each post not on every single page.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if you are in a post with [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) or in the home with [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home).

```
function funny_cat_filter( $content ) {
    if (is_single() || is_home())
        $content .= '<img src="(image url)"/>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'funny_cat_filter' );
```

Comment: Hey, this did something else that I wanted. This removed it on pages but also removed it on the main page (where you see all the posts) and only added it to the single post pages. I want it to be shown on the main page separating the posts' excerpts. Thanks.

Comment: @user3088451 If you want it in your home, add `is_home()`. I edited my answer.